# jqGrid enter key handler

Tags: jqgrid

We am using jQrid version 3.8.1. The `keys` property is set to true so the user can save by hitting the `Enter` key. Is there any way to run a javascript function after the user hits `Enter` but before the save occurs? We need to do some validation and potentially prompt the user that the save will have certain side effects.

Comment: You should upgrade retro version 3.8.1 to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.12.1, which I published today. More recent version of jqGrid have `beforeSaveRow` callback which you can use for example. Additionally there are exist standard validation possibility (`editrules`), which you can use for validation. Alternatively you can don't use `keys: true` and bind your custom `keydown` function inside of `oneditfunc`.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, unfortunately upgrading jgGrid isn't an option at this point.  But you solution of adding a keydown handler on the oneditfunc is right on the money. Thank you very much! If you want to put that in an answer to this question I'll be glad to give you the points. Otherwise I'll create my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can don't use `keys: true` and bind your custom `keydown` function inside of `oneditfunc`. [Here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.12.1/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L178-L189) you can see what jqGrid do in case of usage `keys: true`. You can implement close things, but you should use the close code which you will find in `grid.inlinedit.js` of 3.8.1. It's mostly the same but using the long form (non object form) of `saveRow` parameters (`.jqGrid("saveRow", rowid, succesfunc, url, extraparam, aftersavefunc, errorfunc, afterrestorefunc);`)